# How do I find the response time of a NSURLSession / Request?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I have found the following code at https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/2y1r5s/help_how_do_i_find_the_response_time_of_a/

> ```
> //Do this before your NSURLSession.dataTaskWithRequest
>     var start:NSTimeInterval = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
> // print response time
> //Do this during your NSURLSession.dataTaskWithRequest
>     var timeResponse:NSTimeInterval = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() - start
> ```

It won't help if I make the request more than once at a particular time. It will show the time difference between last request made and the first response received time. Is there any any other way to find it?

Comment: You need to store multiple start timestamps, say in a dictionary, so that you can correlate the response time against the request

Comment: I think you taken the code from this URL - https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/2y1r5s/help_how_do_i_find_the_response_time_of_a/

Comment: check the alternate answer // before
let started = NSDate()
// after
let interval = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(started)

Comment: But for that also I have to maintain multiple time stamps. Is there any other way.